# Javascript addEventListener not working for a specific element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am running into a strange issue: I create 8 different HTML elements using Javasript (in almost exactly the same way for each one) and add event listeners to them all, but 1 specific element does not have the event listener added.

Here is the code for one of the elements that works well:

```
var primaryProductImageLink = document.createElement("a");
primaryProductImageLink.setAttribute("id", "primaryProductImageLink");
primaryProductImageLink.setAttribute("href", result.primaryProduct.pageLink);
primaryProductImageLink.setAttribute("data-resultRequestID", getResultResponse.resultRequestID);
primaryProductImageLink.setAttribute("data-linkName", "primaryProduct");
primaryProductImageLink.addEventListener("click", clickedLinkInResultSection);
```

And here is the code for the element which does not have any event listeners applied:

```
var primaryProductNameLink = document.createElement("a");
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("id", "primaryProductNameLink");
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("href", result.primaryProduct.pageLink);
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("data-resultRequestID", getResultResponse.resultRequestID);
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("data-linkName", "primaryProduct");
primaryProductNameLink.addEventListener("click", clickedLinkInResultSection);
```

When I clear my cache, upload changes, and view the page I run the following commands and it confirms event listeners are added to the first element but not the second:

> getEventListeners(document.getElementById("primaryProductImageLink"));
>   {click: Array(1)}
>   getEventListeners(document.getElementById("primaryProductNameLink"));
>   {}

However, if I add the following code to the very end of my Javascript, the event listener is successfully added to the primaryProductNameLink element:

```
document.getElementById("primaryProductNameLink").addEventListener("click", clickedLinkInResultSection);
```

Verification:

> getEventListeners(document.getElementById("primaryProductNameLink"));
>   {click: Array(1)}

I have tried adding different event listeners to this element, but none have worked. I added test attributes as well, and they show up just fine. Test code:

```
var primaryProductNameLink = document.createElement("a");
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("id", "primaryProductNameLink");
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("href", result.primaryProduct.pageLink);
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("data-resultRequestID", getResultResponse.resultRequestID);
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("data-linkName", "primaryProduct");
primaryProductNameLink.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { console.log("test"); });
primaryProductNameLink.addEventListener("mouseout", function() { console.log("test"); });
primaryProductNameLink.addEventListener("click", clickedLinkInResultSection);
primaryProductNameLink.setAttribute("data-test", "test");
```

Result:
[image: Event listeners issue]
.

I have gone through my whole Javascript file and there are no other references to "primaryProductNameLink" which could possibly remove any event listeners.

I know there are workarounds (like the one I showed by adding the event listener at the end of the script), but I am genuinely curious and would love to know what is causing this issue. Thanks!

EDIT: Full Javascript can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/fbchm4ov/ (The elements described in my post are only generated once the 4 questions are answered.)

Comment: Sorry for commenting three times now. jsFiddle would be great, I'd love to dig into this.

Comment: Maybe `clickedLinkInResultSection` is undefined in the scope you are binding in? I can only guess atm.

Comment: @Syntac I have added a jsfiddle link with the full javascript file. The code that generates these elements is in the function "getProductSelectorResultCallback".

Comment: kk, Ill have a look. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still on it, trying to figure out the exact problem. What I have found out so far: Things are starting to break the moment you start modifying `primaryProductInfoDiv.innerHTML`. Why is that a problem? Well, you first add real DOM elements, and then you start handling  `primaryProductInfoDiv.innerHTML` as plain text again, which I believe to destroy the information you had about EventListeners before. In general, using `innerHTML` to that extent is bad practice. I'd encourage you to don't use it at all, which would fix your problem, I believe.

Comment: Since the image `primaryProductImageLink` isn't a child of `primaryProductInfoDiv`, it isn't affected by that problem. That's the reason, it works just fine. Another thing: The reason, why adding the EventListener later worked is that you added it AFTER the changes to `innerHTML`, so this time it didn't get lost while editing `innerHTML`.

Comment: Would love to hear some feedback!

Comment: @Syntac You were absolutely right, I replaced the parent's "innerHTML +=" lines by creating and appending children and now the listener works correctly on all the elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fiddle I read that you append `primaryProductNameLink` to `primaryProductInfoDiv` and later after that you modify `primaryProductInfoDiv` by using `primaryProductInfoDiv.innerHTML +=`.

When you set `innerHTML` property, you are overwriting existing HTML that was set there.

Doing

```
 primaryProductInfoDiv.innerHTML += '<br>';
```

is basically creating a new HTML structure using the current innerHTML structure plus `<br>` and assign it to innerHTML. Your event handler is attached to the old innerHTML, not the new one.

So instead of doing concatenation, we can use `createElement` and `appendChild` to avoid such a problem.

Comment: You nailed it. I replaced all the "primaryProductInfoDiv.innerHTML +=" lines by creating and appending the elements and now the listener is found on primaryProductNameLink. Thanks!